# Should food safety questions be considered on topic, and if so what, if any, limits should there be?

Tags: discussion

The question is in the title. By limits I mean, for example, should food preparation questions be allowed even though those are more directly on topic in Cooking.SE?

This question was prompted by [this question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/question-on-food-safety-put-on-hold-as-not-medical-sciences) and the ensuing comments.

Comment: Reminder: [Where to ask questions about food](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/259326) This meta-meta post may need an edit after we finish this?

Comment: @LangLangC Good find.

Answer (score 2):

Condensed from comments below a more [specific main-question related post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1031/question-on-food-safety-put-on-hold-as-not-medical-sciences?noredirect=1&lq=1), this seems to be the emerging opinion:

While we strive to be *much stricter than before* on posts related to food in terms of nutrition, we can be more accepting on food safety.

Food-safety related question are on-topic in principle.

Mainly we want questions more clearly dustinguishable from basic CookingSE *and* basic BiologySE.

But it's kind of a slippery slope and the questions would have to be very narrow. 
For example, "To what temperature do I need to cook chicken?" is a food safety question, but it's also clearly more appropriate on Cooking.SE. "Which bacteria tend to grow on chicken under what conditions?" goes to BiologySE.

Our turf: "How high is the epidemiological impact or risk of salmonella infections? How is this best prevented or treated?"

That would mean that *food preparation* questions are under special scrutiny.

But as long as the primary intent and scope of the question are framed from a public health, disease prevention perspective – and of course the question presents prior research from scientific-oriented sources, instead of e.g. house-keeping or cookbooks – the it looks more like a good fit for this site.

Questions reviewers or voters might consider in evaluating such a question:

1. Is the primary content related to public health, disease prevention, research? -> +
2. Is that a question that is asked and answered in the medical literature? -> +
3. Is the primary content of the question studied and disseminated by public health organizations? -> +

One real life xample from main would be:

> [Should one avoid consuming durians when drinking alcohol?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/18174/should-one-avoid-consuming-durians-when-drinking-alcohol)

Discussed in the medical literature, no good match for cooking and better fitting on MedSci than biology?

……***to be done:*** more or better examples, questions to evaluate where a positive answer leads to negative assessment……

Comment: If anyone knows or finds other *real examples* from our site that fits the above, please add them.

Comment: So what is your opinion on the initiating question on fridges keeping food fresh?  Do you agree this is a Cooking.SE question like the question on cooking temperatures for chicken or is this on-topic here?

Comment: @ChrisRogers That's a difficult one, as what we are discussing here is by far not the only problem the Q has. I'd say that the underlying Q *can* be on-topic here. In its current form it is certainly not. It's not researched, too basic, too broad, presents some 'strange' logic etc. My only real concern is that we just state that one reason for closure (and keep on arguing here) when all the other reasons *should* also lead to closure. // Taken as is, Cooking and Us should produce quite different answers. I wonder whether Cooking has meta-Qs focusing on public health?